# Sorting table with JS plugin causes bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

I've a problem with a sorting JS plugin for my tables. It's named "Sortable". I've did everything described in the documentation to setup everything. The sorting works but there is an issue with dates and prices.

So when I sort for example a date column ascending, the rows looking like this:

1. 22.10.2018
2. 23.02.2019
3. 28.02.2019
4. 28.12.2018

You can see the date config here:

https://github.hubspot.com/sortable/api/options/

Maybe it's a problem with the german date format but I don't know exactly how to fix this. Maybe you can take a look at it? This would be really awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's sorted in alphabetic order. because german date format can't be parsed by javascript `Date.parse`. You should add custom type.

Here’s how Sortable internally sets up the defaults.

```
sortable.setupTypes [{
  name: 'numeric'
  defaultSortDirection: 'descending'
  match: (a) -> a.match numberRegExp
  comparator: (a) -> parseFloat(a.replace(/[^0-9.-]/g, ''), 10) or 0
}, {
  name: 'date'
  defaultSortDirection: 'ascending'
  reverse: true
  match: (a) -> not isNaN Date.parse a
  comparator: (a) -> Date.parse(a) or 0
}, {
  name: 'alpha'
  defaultSortDirection: 'ascending'
  match: -> true
  compare: (a, b) -> a.localeCompare b
}]
```

note `match` and `comparator` of `date` type.
change those to:

```
  match: (a) -> not isNaN Date.parse a.split('.').reverse().join('.')
  comparator: (a) -> Date.parse(a.split('.').reverse().join('.')) or 0
```

and add these after sortable.init() call.

By the way, this is coffeescript. so use it accordingly.

Comment: This is what I've tried. But it's still sorting not correctly. Maybe because of the german date format?

Comment: yes it's because of the german date format.  Date.parse('22.10.2018') is NaN. date type implementation use this code. You can set custom type for this

Comment: How do I need to modify this to reach my goal?

Comment: I changed my answer. please check

Comment: Awesome mate. Works great, thanks! Do you want to help me with another filter? It's about filtering prices but there is a bit of a problem. I would describe this in a new question.